# YII2 как передать запрос посредством AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, yii2

Нужно передать массив идшников посредством `AJAX` в `php`, но в консоли вылезает ошибка 400 (неверные параметры)

Написал такой код на `js`:

```
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var body = JSON.stringify({
            id: checkedInputTagsArray //массив идшников
        });
        console.log(body);
        xhr.open('POST', '/products/' + action , true); //action - параметр функции
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
        xhr.send(body);
```

Код на `php`:

```
    $request = Yii::$app->request;
    if (!$request->isAjax) {
        return "not ajax";
    }
    $json = json_encode($request->getBodyParams());
    return $json;
```

Да, он ничего не делает, но мне бы сначала установить подключение и посмотреть, передаются ли данные.

Есть вообще разница между `open(..., /model/action)` и `open(..., http://host/model/action)`? Просто с хостом у меня дебагер не отображает запросы аякс...

Comment: Убедитесь что вы передаете, crf token более подробнее тут: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27126356/7678419

Comment: @SergeyN, да, теперь запрос доходит до сервера, но сервер возвращает только 500 ошибку.

Comment: Теперь у вас ошибка на стороне сервера :)
Попробуйте заменить `json_encode` на `json_decode` т.к функция encode преобразует объект в JSON строку а вам нужно сделать обратное действие

Comment: @SergeyN, да, точно, перепутал. спасибо. но я не могу понять, как принять данные и вернуть их для просмотра?

Comment: Если вы хотите сделать просто вернуть данные которые оправили на сервер воспользуйтесь этим примером: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41675108/7678419

Comment: @SergeyN, сделал, но все равно не могу вернуть тело запроса.

Comment: Что возвращается в ответе сервера ?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85137/discussion-between-dasauser-and-sergeyn).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

необходимо было отключить csrf валидацию и добавить `Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON;` в соответствующий экшен